# Unselect a DrawLine after its drawn

Tags: java, teechart

After I draw a DrawLine it stays selected. I would like them to be un-selected after its drawn.

How do I un-select a DrawLine after its drawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DrawLine.setEnableSelect(false)`](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/JavaDoc/com/steema/teechart/tools/DrawLine.html#setEnableSelect%28boolean%29)  (WAG from examining the JavaDocs of an API I'd never heard of before right now).

Comment: DrawLine.setEnableSelect(false) disables the ability to select any DrawLines. I was hoping there was a way to un-select a line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this method available then use this: `DrawLine.setSelectNewLines` or you can use [`setSelected(null)`](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/JavaDoc/com/steema/teechart/tools/DrawLine.html#setSelected%28com.steema.teechart.tools.DrawLineItem%29) to un-select the newly drawn item. You also need to add [`DrawLineListener`](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/JavaDoc/com/steema/teechart/tools/DrawLine.DrawLineListener.html) so you can listen to new line to use this function. Sample lines of code will be:

```
    drawLine.addDrawLineListener(new DrawLineListener() {
        @Override
        public void lineSelected(ChangeEvent ce) {}
        @Override
        public void lineNew(ChangeEvent ce) {
            drawLine.setSelected(null);
        }
    });
```